# How to get "like" list of all facebooks, In addition to facebook api

Tags: node.js

Can only get a partial list, can not get a full list

Log in to your facebook and copy your cookie here

```
const request = require('request').defaults({
  headers: {
    'cookie': '', #input your cookie
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36'
  }
});
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const async = require('async');
const parse = require('url-parse');
```

This URL is what I want to get "like" list
    var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/fetch/?limit=50&shown_ids=&total_count=999999&ft_ent_identifier=10161786924635725&__a=1';

```
getActionList(url, (list)=>{
 console.log(list.length);
})


function getActionList(url , callback){

  var ft_ent_identifier = parse(url, true).query.ft_ent_identifier

  request(url, (err, res, body)=>{

      var data = JSON.parse(body.replace('for (;;);', ''))
      // var html = data.jsmods.markup[0][1].__html
      var html = data.domops[0][3].__html
      var $ = cheerio.load(html)

      var list = $('._5j0e a').map((index, obj)=>{
        return {
            id: JSON.parse($(obj).attr('data-gt')).engagement.eng_tid,
            name: $(obj).text(),
            link: $(obj).attr('href'),
        }
      }).get()

      var html = data.domops[1][3].__html
      var $ = cheerio.load(html)
      if($('.uiMorePager').length){
        var url = 'https://www.facebook.com' + $('.uiMorePager a').attr('href') + `&__a=1`
        getMoreList(url, (moreList)=>{
          callback(list.concat(moreList))
        })
      }else{
          callback(list)
      }
  })
}

function getMoreList(url, callback){
  var ft_ent_identifier = parse(url, true).query.ft_ent_identifier
  request(url, (err, res, body)=>{
    var data = JSON.parse(body.replace('for (;;);', ''))
    var html = data.domops[0][3].__html;
    var $ = cheerio.load(html)
    var list = $('._5j0e a').map((index, obj)=>{
      return {
          id: JSON.parse($(obj).attr('data-gt')).engagement.eng_tid,
          name: $(obj).text(),
          link: $(obj).attr('href'),
      }
    }).get()

    if(data.domops[1][3]){
      var html = data.domops[1][3].__html;
      var $ = cheerio.load(html)
      var url = 'https://www.facebook.com' + $('.uiMorePager a').attr('href') + `&ft_ent_identifier=${ft_ent_identifier}&__a=1`
      getMoreList(url, (moreList)=>{
        callback(list.concat(moreList))
      })
    }else{
        callback(list)
    }
  })
}
```

Get a complete list